# How to determine the maxium ram supportted on a multi cpu s socket motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, xeon, processor-socket

In the past only the motherboard specification mattered.
But since memory controllers moved onto the cpu, it s the cpu which defines the maximum memory supported by the system.

In the case of motherboard with a single socket, the answer is easy. However, how does this work on a motherboard with more than one cpu (not cores)?
Is the maximum memory supportted determined by the lowest value of the worst cpu? Or does the maximum supportted ram of each cpu adds up?

For example if I have a cpu supportting 2TiB of ram, and a second cpu on the same motherboard supportting 4TiB of ram (where the motherboard supports 7.5Tb of ram), will the system support only 2TiB of ram (from the lowest supportted value) or 6TiB (4TiB+2TiB)?

Answer (score 0):

First off, cpus need to match.  If the mobo supports it, the available ram will be number of cpus times maximum ram/cpu.  And while it may be possible to get nearly identical cpus to run on a multi cpu mobo (i.e. xeon 5660 with a xeon 5690) it is generally a bad idea and you may not have all cores available.

Comment: They need to match even if both are supportted by the mainboard?

Comment: Yes.  Even if you could get non matching cpus to work with the board you are almost certainly looking at unpredictable problems.  Imagine welding two halves of different V8 engines together.

Comment: My plan was using a Intel® Xeon® Gold 6250L for fast per thread performance along a Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8280L for performance on multithreaded applications. Both are from the same generation and uses the same type of qpi link. The motherboard is Intel made. Would it work?

Comment: Don't know...  Are the clock speeds the same??  Let me know.

Comment: There an additional cpu now. Sorry for the delay. Here s the details https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=192472,202780,205683